# Est-ce que l’on peut dire “trébucher sur quelqu’un” ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Dans la plupart des contextes, je ne vois que :

- “je trébuche contre quelque chose et les mots” et “ je le fais trébucher”

Est-ce que l’on peut dire aussi :

- “je trébuche sur Jean” comme dans des séries romantiques ou alors dit-on plutôt “je tombe sur Jean” ?

Comment: Réponse courte : oui, si cette personne est couchée par terre.

Comment: Pourquoi une série romantique?

Comment: @Lambie Ce sont plutôt des séries asiatiques, voici l’exemple : https://youtu.be/1n_VhSZSvhc

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi les mots tomber sur et trëbucher sur aient un rapport spécifique à quelque chose de romantique.

Comment: Ça ressemble à _tomber dans les bras de quelqu'un_ mais littéralement.

Answer (score 2):

On peut dire les deux mais ça n'a pas le même sens.

- Je trébuche sur Jean.
  Sens propre du verbe *trébucher*, contexte : il fait noir et j'avance à tâtons dans une pièce où tout le monde est allongé par terre, oups, mon bien cogne Jean, je peux dire alors que « je trébuche sur Jean » (« trébucher contre » Jean serait plus approprié mais on entend souvent « trébucher sur » quelque chose), *trébucher* c'est perdre l'équilibre, après avoir trébuché soit j'arrive à me redresser, soit je tombe sur Jean (c'est à dire que je me retrouve allongé sur lui).
- Je tombe sur Jean.
  1- Pour le sens propre voir ci-dessus.
  2- Au sens figuré « tomber sur quelqu'un — ou quelque chose »  c'est le **rencontrer par hasard**. Et non, on ne peut pas employer « trébucher sur quelqu'un » pour dire qu'on le rencontre par hasard.

Au sens figuré *trébucher* veut dire hésiter (« trébucher sur les mots »).